# ssl or is there any other way?

Tags: database, security

I am trying to secure online transaction between application server and database. One-way is SSL, but is there any other way of securing transaction between them. I am trying to reduce the overhead in securing the line. Are there any tool or api's which I can integrate with the application server or deploy on it.

/SR

Comment: What platform? What web server? What database? Different ones will lend themselves to different solutions.

Answer (score 1):

Sure, but it requires a thoughtful review of your architecture.  If you have a dedicated line between your application and your database, the connection could be encrypted at the network layer.

I'm a bit surprised that your application server and your database are not within the same trust boundary.  Is this an app in the cloud?

Answer (score 0):

SSL is by far the best way, its extremely secure and absolutely free.  If your database or another application doesn't support SSL then you can use a free SSL VPN such as OpenVPN.  This will create a secure transport layer connection between 2 machines.

If you are connecting to a database on the local machine then there is no point in a secure transport layer connection.  However you should firewall off the database port,  for instance MySQL uses tcp 3306.

Comment: You forgot to mention that it's cross-platform, too :)